# Add/attach AWS IAM Role to EC2 instance via terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-iam, terraform-provider-aws, aws-roles

i have a quick question here..
I am using terraform to deploy ec2 instances on AWS, and i need a way to attach AWS IAM Role to the instance.

I have created manuall on AWS console an IAM Policy + role, and attached to EC2 instance and tested, it works.
Now i need to use same role (i created earlier manually) to automatically attach to new ec2 instances via terraform

I am tring to do this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "test-ec2" {
  ami                         = "ami-xxxxxxxxxx"
  instance_type               = "t3.large"
  iam_instance_profile        = "arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/my-role-name" ## I know i am missing something here... (:facepalm:)
  key_name                    = "my-key"
  subnet_id                   = "subnet-some-subnet-d"
  vpc_security_group_ids      = ["sg-some-group-id"]
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  root_block_device {
    delete_on_termination = true
    volume_type           = "gp3"
    volume_size           = 40
}
```

The reason i am doing it that way (create manualy role once and not via terraform) is becouse i dont
want to give terraform ability to create roles and permissions, only ec2 instances and attach only existing
role, less permissions on jenkins/terraform = better security (at least this is what i think is proper..)

This is the error I get:

```
Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterValue: Value (arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/my-role-name) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name    status code: 400, request id: xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx  with aws_instance.test-ec2, on main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_instance" "test-ec2": 11: resource "aws_instance" "test-ec2" {
```

Comment: You already setup `iam_instance_profile` in your TF code. So what's wrong with it? What errors do you get?

Comment: @Marcin 
this is the error i get
`Error: creating EC2 Instance: InvalidParameterValue: Value (arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/my-role-name) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name
   status code: 400, request id: xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx

with aws_instance.test-ec2,
on main.tf line 11, in resource "aws_instance" "test-ec2":
11: resource "aws_instance" "test-ec2" {`

Comment: Iam_instance_profile should be the name not the arn

Comment: iam_instance_profile - (Optional) IAM Instance Profile to launch the instance with. Specified as the name of the Instance Profile

Comment: @ChrisDoyle, yes, i have seen that on documentation, yet, if i am to use name, i need to specify it in resource "aws_iam_role".
and "aws_iam_role" means that terraform will actually create a new role each time it runs, and this is not what is required.

I simply try to use a role/policy (profile) in AWS i have created earlier to use with new EC2 instances, not create new role/policy/profile each time i run TF..

the documentation on TF website is very vague about this it seems.. or maybe i am not looking in right direction.. :facepalm:

Comment: Just pass it as a string. `iam_instance_profile = "my-role-name"` you don't need to create it with terraform if it's already defined

Comment: @ChrisDoyle
you were right!!
It works now... well, i had to add more permissions to server from which terraform was running (jenkins machine), but it actually works now :D

thanx!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid IAM Instance Profile name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213153/invalid-iam-instance-profile-name)

Answer (score 1):

You can get an error like this when specifying a role name directly on the instance's `iam_instance_profile`. *Sometimes they have the same name as the role, which can make it hard to diagnose the issue*.

When terraforming existing resources this can be easy to miss - you need a `aws_iam_instance_profile` resource in addition to the `aws_iam_role`.

Ex:

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "test_profile" {
  name = "test_profile"
  role = aws_iam_role.role.name
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.test_profile.name
}
```

Related Resources

[Terraform aws_iam_instance_profile resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/iam_instance_profile)

[AWS IAM Roles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html)

[AWS Instance Profiles](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html)