# Invalid IAM Instance Profile name - Value for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm deploying an EC2 instance using terraform but getting the below error

`Value (arn:aws:iam::000000000:instance-profile/poc-profile) for parameter iamInstanceProfile.name is invalid. Invalid IAM Instance Profile name`

I'm using our base module for EC2 and below is a snippet of my code (omitted other resources)

```
module "ec2_poc" {
  iam_instance_profile   = aws_iam_instance_profile.base_profile.arn
}
```

in the tf plan, i'm seeing this and it matches the instance profile arn when checked from aws console

`+ iam_instance_profile                 = "arn:aws:iam::000000000:instance-profile/poc-profile"`

`ec2_poc` module:

```
resource "aws_instance" "base_instance" {
  count = var.count_instances
  ami = var.ami_id
  instance_type = var.instance_type
  ebs_optimized = var.ebs_optimized
  ipv6_address_count = var.ipv6_address_count
  vpc_security_group_ids = var.sg_ids
  subnet_id = var.instance_subnets[count.index % length(var.instance_subnets)]
  iam_instance_profile = var.iam_instance_profile
  disable_api_termination = var.disable_api_termination
  availability_zone = var.availability_zones == "" ? var.availability_zones : var.availability_zones[count.index % length(var.availability_zones)]

  tags = (merge(var.tags_basic, var.tags_extra, tomap({
     Name             = replace(var.tags_extra["Name"], "i_count", format("%02d", count.index + 1))
     tag_monthly_cost = "${ceil(1.0 * lookup(var.ec2_cost, var.instance_type) * 24.0 * 30.0)}"
   })))

  root_block_device {
    volume_type = var.default_volume_type
    volume_size = var.root_block_device_size
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
    ignore_changes        = [ami]
  }

  metadata_options {
    http_endpoint               = "enabled"
    http_tokens                 = "required"
    http_put_response_hop_limit = 2
  }

  credit_specification {
    cpu_credits = var.cpu_credits
  }
}

resource "aws_ebs_volume" "instance_system_volume" {
  count = length(var.extra_ebs_volumes) * var.count_instances
  encrypted = var.encrypted
  kms_key_id = var.kms_key_arn
  type              = lookup(var.extra_ebs_volume_type, lookup(var.tag_disk_location, var.extra_ebs_volumes[count.index % length(var.extra_ebs_volumes)]), "${var.default_ebs_volume_type}")
  availability_zone = element(aws_instance.base_instance.*.availability_zone, floor(count.index / length(var.extra_ebs_volumes)))

   # size = "${floor(lookup(var.default_ebs_vol_sizes,
   #   var.tag_disk_location[var.extra_ebs_volumes[count.index % length(var.extra_ebs_volumes)]]))}"

   size = (floor(lookup(merge(var.default_ebs_vol_sizes, var.ebs_vol_sizes),
   var.tag_disk_location[var.extra_ebs_volumes[count.index % length(var.extra_ebs_volumes)]])))

   tags = (merge(var.tags_basic, var.tags_extra,
     tomap({
        Name = format("%s", lower("${replace(var.tags_extra["Name"], "i_count", format("%02d", floor(count.index / length(var.extra_ebs_volumes)) + 1))} ${var.txt_delimiter}${var.extra_ebs_volumes[count.index % length(var.extra_ebs_volumes)]}"))
     })
   ))

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["availability_zone"]
  }
}

resource "aws_volume_attachment" "instance_ebs_attachment" {
  count        = length(var.extra_ebs_volumes) * var.count_instances
  device_name  = format("%s", lower("/dev/${var.extra_ebs_volumes[count.index % length(var.extra_ebs_volumes)]}"))
  volume_id    = element(aws_ebs_volume.instance_system_volume.*.id, count.index)
  instance_id  = element(aws_instance.base_instance.*.id, floor(count.index / length(var.extra_ebs_volumes)))
  force_detach = true

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = ["instance_id", "volume_id"]
  }
}

resource "null_resource" "lvm_housekeeping" {
  triggers = {
    ebs_volume_ids = "${join(",", aws_volume_attachment.instance_ebs_attachment.*.volume_id)}"
  }
}
```

`iam_instance_profile`:

```
resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "base_profile" {
  name = var.base_profile_name
  role = aws_iam_role.base_role.name

  tags = (merge(var.tags,
    tomap({
      tags_imds_required              = false
      tags_persistent_instance        = false
      tags_cost_center                = lookup(var.tags, "tags_cost_center", "undefined")
      tags_created_via                = lookup(var.tags, "tags_created_via", "Pipeline")
      tags_public                     = false
      tags_system_criticality         = "undefined"
      tags_environment                = lookup(var.tags, "tags_environment", "undefined")
      tags_external_shared            = false
    })
  ))
}
```

IAM role:

```
resource "aws_iam_role" "base_role" {
  name = var.base_role_name

  assume_role_policy = var.assume_role_policy != ""  ? var.assume_role_policy : jsonencode({
      Version = "2012-10-17"
      Statement = [
        {
          Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
          Effect = "Allow"
          Sid    = ""
          Principal = {
            Service = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
          }
        },
      ]
    })

  tags = (merge(var.tags,
    tomap({
      Name                            = var.base_role_name
      tags_imds_required              = false
      tags_persistent_instance        = false
      tags_application_code           = lookup(var.tags, "tags_application_code", "undefined")
      tags_created_via                = lookup(var.tags, "tags_created_via", "Pipeline")
      tags_public                     = false
      tags_system_criticality         = "undefined"
      tags_environment                = lookup(var.tags, "tags_environment", "undefined")
      tags_external_shared            = false
       })
   ))
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ec2_describe" {
  name = "ec2_describe_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.base_role.name
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
     Statement = [
       {
        Action = ["ec2:Describe*"]
        Effect = "Allow"
        Resource = "*"
       }
     ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ec2_volumes" {
  name = "ec2_volume_attachment_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.base_role.name
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
        "Action": [
           "ec2:AttachVolume",
           "ec2:DetachVolume"
        ]
        Effect = "Allow"
        Resource = "*"
      }
     ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ecr_policy" {
  name = "ec2_ecr_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.base_role.name
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
         "Sid": "ECR",
         "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
               "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
               "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
               "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
               "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
               "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
               "ecr:ListImages",
               "ecr:DescribeImages",
               "ecr:BatchGetImage",
               "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicy",
               "ecr:GetLifecyclePolicyPreview",
               "ecr:ListTagsForResource",
               "ecr:DescribeImageScanFindings"
         ],
         "Resource": "*"
       }
     ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ec2_s3_policy" {
  name = "ec2_s3_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.base_role.name
  policy = jsonencode({
     Version = "2012-10-17"
     Statement = [
       {
          "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
          "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
          ],
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Resource": [
             "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}"
          ]
        },
        {
         "Sid": "HomeDirObjectAccess",
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:DeleteObject",
            "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObjectVersion",
            "s3:GetObjectACL",
            "s3:PutObjectACL"
         ],
         "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}/*"
       }
     ]
  })
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy" "ssm_policy" {
  name = "ec2_ssm_policy"
  role = aws_iam_role.base_role.name
  policy = jsonencode({
    Version = "2012-10-17"
    Statement = [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": "ssm:StartSession",
         "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ssm:*:*:document/AWS-StartSSHSession"
         ]
       },
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
           "ssm:DescribeAssociation",
           "ssm:GetDeployablePatchSnapshotForInstance",
           "ssm:GetDocument",
           "ssm:DescribeDocument",
           "ssm:GetManifest",
           "ssm:GetParameter",
           "ssm:GetParameters",
           "ssm:ListAssociations",
           "ssm:ListInstanceAssociations",
           "ssm:PutInventory",
           "ssm:PutComplianceItems",
           "ssm:PutConfigurePackageResult",
           "ssm:UpdateAssociationStatus",
           "ssm:UpdateInstanceAssociationStatus",
           "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation"
         ],
           "Resource": "*"
         },
         {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
              "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
              "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
              "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
              "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel"
            ],
           "Resource": "*"
          },
          {
           "Action": [
              "logs:CreateLogStream",
              "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
              "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
              "logs:PutLogEvents"
           ],
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Resource": "*"
           },
           }
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
              "ec2messages:AcknowledgeMessage",
              "ec2messages:DeleteMessage",
              "ec2messages:FailMessage",
              "ec2messages:GetEndpoint",
              "ec2messages:GetMessages",
              "ec2messages:SendReply"
            ],
           "Resource": "*"
         }
      ]
  })
}
```

any ideas on what could be causing the above error? thank you!

Comment: What is module `ec2_atlassian_discovery_poc` module? What is `iam_instance_profile` in the module? How it is used and defined ? Sadly your question is unclear and lacks details.

Comment: hello sorry about that, i've updated the post with more details.. thanks

Comment: What is the **full** error message, showing exact line where it occurs in the code?

Comment: there is no error when running tf apply just stuck on this Still creating... [2m0s elapsed][0m[0m then when checked on Datadog that's the full error message

Comment: What do you mean there is no error? You literally wrote "getting the below error" in the question and provided partial output of the error.

Comment: that is the full error message, it's not showing me exact line where it occurs in the code that's why i'm unable to troubleshoot further

Comment: As a side note, shouldn't the `name` attribute of the `aws_iam_instance_profile` be used and not the ARN?

Comment: @MarkoE do you mean iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.base_profile.name ? I tried this also iam_instance_profile = var.base_profile_name and declared the value in tfvar but getting the same error

Comment: @Michael Can you add the IAM role resource to the question as well?

Comment: I meant the terraform code for it. And do you have a properly defined trust policy for the role?

Comment: @MarkoE i've added the IAM role tf code in the question as requested, thanks

Comment: @MarkoE i just noticed now on IAM instance profile tf code, i've declared role = aws_iam_role.base_role.name.. i used the name attribute, so i'm thinking if i should do the same on the EC2 instance tf code,  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.base_profile.name like what you mentioned earlier

Comment: Well, I would say yes. So when calling the module try with: `iam_instance_profile   = aws_iam_instance_profile.base_profile.name`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invalid IAM Instance Profile name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213153/invalid-iam-instance-profile-name)